# How to write unittest for function which accepts default argument - without writing separate assert for the default case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following is the code in app.py:

```
def my_function(grade='other'):
    return grade.lower()
```

The function accepts argument `grade`. It defaults to `other` when no argument is passed.

I am writing unittest for this function:

```
grades = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for grade in grades:
    self.assertEqual(my_function(grade.lower()), grade.lower())
```

If I change grades to `grades = [None, 'A', 'B', 'C']` then I get an error that NoneType does not support lower().

I know that I can add the following code to the above code which will be a separate assert to test the deafult:

```
self.assertEqual(my_function(), 'other')
```

But is there any way to test the default argument case without writing separate assert for it?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, passing `None` as a parameter does not trigger its default value. That's why you're getting the `AttributeError`.

As for your real question you have several ways of doing it but you should probably go with `self.assertEqual(my_function(), 'other')`:

#### inspect.getargspec

**I (and some other people in comments) strongly advise against using this beyond toying purposes**

```
from inspect import getargspec

grades = ['A', 'B', 'C', getargspec(my_function).defaults[0]]
for grade in grades:
    self.assertEqual(my_function(grade.lower()), grade.lower())
```

#### using a sentinel

(here it's `None`, but if `None` is an acceptable value, go with whatever)

```
def my_function(grade=None):
    if grade is None:
        grade = "other"
    return grade.lower()
```

Comment: Mentioning `inspect` probably does more harm than good. The test should not rely on `my_function` being implemented with a specific, or any, default parameter value.

Comment: OP asks if there is a way of doing it, not what's the best or even if there is a good way of doing. And while I agree with you, `inspect` can still do it. I can add further warning about it being wrong though.